# variable (element).style is undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="10"></textarea>
    <span id="counter">10</span>
    <script>
        let textArea=document.getElementById('textarea'),
        counter=document.getElementById('counter'),
        number=counter.innerHTML;
        textArea.oninput=function(){
        counter.innerHTML=number-textArea.value.length;
        if(number==0){
            number.style.color="red";//number.style is undefined
        }else{
            number.style.color="black";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

why it  says variable (element).style is undefined?
I tried .style.color="red"; on a different code & it works!

Comment: `number` is a String (because you do `number=counter.innerHTML;`). You can't change the style of a String. Maybe you want to change the style of `counter` instead?

Comment: You should be setting `style` on `counter` since `counter` is the `span` element that holds the text you wish to style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you have to compare against counter.innerHTML because you update its value.
  The value of counter doesn't change and will all the time be 10 as you can see in the snippet below.
- Second the value of number is counter.innerHTML;

---

```
number=counter.innerHTML;
```

This means that is does not have a style.color property instead you should set the style.color of your counter element.

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="10"></textarea>
    <span id="counter">10</span>
    <script>
        let textArea=document.getElementById('textarea'),
        counter=document.getElementById('counter'),
        number=counter.innerHTML;
        textArea.oninput=function(){
        counter.innerHTML=number-textArea.value.length;
        if(counter.innerHTML==0){
            counter.style.color="red";//number.style is undefined
        }else{
            counter.style.color="black";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Scott Marcus' comment: You let the value of number to be the first value of span which is 10. It won't change oninput. So using it in if statement is not useful because it's always going to be 10. Instead you should use counter.innerHTML like I did in the snippet below.

```js
let textArea=document.getElementById('textarea'),
counter=document.getElementById('counter'),
number=counter.innerHTML;
textArea.oninput=function(){
counter.innerHTML=number-textArea.value.length;
if(counter.innerHTML==0){
    counter.style.color="red";//number.style is undefined
    console.log("here");
}else{
    counter.style.color="black";
    console.log("there");
}
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="10"></textarea>
<span id="counter">10</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Explanation

I assumed you wanted to give user feedback once input length reaches 10 characters.

So the below snippet initializes your constants: textarea, counter and number.

`number` is type casted as an int using the builtin Number function. Then on textarea input the local variable `current` is set to hold the result of your formula: `maxchars(number) - inputchars(textarea)`.

`counter` is updated with `current` and finally I used a ternary to set `counter` color red if 0 otherwise black.

```js
 const textArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
 const counter  = document.getElementById('counter');
 const number   = Number(counter.innerHTML);

 textArea.oninput = function() {
    const current       = number - textArea.value.length;
     
    counter.innerHTML   = current;
    counter.style.color = current === 0 ? "red" : "black";

    return;
 };
```